# Converting a pandas dataframe to a nested dict in Python using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame([["123456", "a", "80", False, "beta", None, None], ["123456", "b", "80", False, "beta", None, None],["7891011", "a", "80", False, "beta", None, None], ["7891011", "b", "80", False, "beta", None, None]], columns = ["device", "variable", "size", "manual", "method","nrow", "ncol"])

>>> my_df.head()
    device variable size  manual method  nrow  ncol
0   123456        a   80   False   beta  None  None
1   123456        b   80   False   beta  None  None
2  7891011        a   80   False   beta  None  None
3  7891011        b   80   False   beta  None  None
```

I want to convert it to the following nested dict structure:

```
{
'123456':
     {
     'a': {
          'size': 80,
          'manual': False,
          'method': 'beta',
          'nrow': None,
          'ncol': None
          },
     'b': {
          'size': 80,
          'manual': False,
          'method': 'beta',
          'nrow': None,
          'ncol': None
          }
     },
'7891011':
     {
     'a': {
          'size': 80,
          'manual': False,
          'method': 'beta',
          'nrow': None,
          'ncol': None
          },
     'b': {
          'size': 80,
          'manual': False,
          'method': 'beta',
          'nrow': None,
          'ncol': None
          }
     }
}
```

I can easily loop through the variables and do some filtering with pandas, but that does not seem very efficient. Is there a way to do that using `df.groupby()`?

Maybe:

```
my_df.groupby(["device", "variable"]).apply(list).to_dict()
```

But that messes up the key names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First group by `device` (level 1) and keep all columns except `device` then set `variable` as index (level 2) and finally convert all columns to dict (level 3). At the end, convert the whole dataframe as a dict.

```
import json

d = df.groupby("device")[["variable", "size", "manual", "method", "nrow", "ncol"]] \
      .apply(lambda x: x.set_index("variable").to_dict(orient="index")) \
      .to_dict()
print(json.dumps(d, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

{
    "123456": {
        "a": {
            "manual": false,
            "method": "beta",
            "ncol": null,
            "nrow": null,
            "size": "80"
        },
        "b": {
            "manual": false,
            "method": "beta",
            "ncol": null,
            "nrow": null,
            "size": "80"
        }
    },
    "7891011": {
        "a": {
            "manual": false,
            "method": "beta",
            "ncol": null,
            "nrow": null,
            "size": "80"
        },
        "b": {
            "manual": false,
            "method": "beta",
            "ncol": null,
            "nrow": null,
            "size": "80"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the required columns to records using `to_dict` and assign the records to the new column in the dataframe, then set the index of dataframe to `device` and `variable` and `unstack` to reshape again followed by `to_dict` with orientation index

```
c = ['device', 'variable']
my_df['rec'] = my_df.drop(c, 1).to_dict('r')
my_df.set_index(c)['rec'].unstack().to_dict('i')
```

---

```
{'123456': {'a': {'size': '80',
                  'manual': False,
                  'method': 'beta',
                  'nrow': None,
                  'ncol': None},
            'b': {'size': '80',
                  'manual': False,
                  'method': 'beta',
                  'nrow': None,
                  'ncol': None}},
 '7891011': {'a': {'size': '80',
                   'manual': False,
                   'method': 'beta',
                   'nrow': None,
                   'ncol': None},
             'b': {'size': '80',
                   'manual': False,
                   'method': 'beta',
                   'nrow': None,
                   'ncol': None}}}
```